# Inferior octave freezes

Tags: emacs, octave

In emacs octave-mode, when I type M-x run-octave the command freezes so I do C-g to escape. I can switch to the *Inferior Octave* buffer with C-x b but there is no prompt, just the welcome message. C-c i l also does not work.

Comment: Which version of Octave do you have installed? Do you get anything interesting in `*Messages*`? `C-c i` doesn't seem to be bound to anything in my version of Octave mode or Inferior Octave mode. What is it meant to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Emacs 24.3.1 simply add `PS1(">> ")` to `~/.octaverc`. No need to change the value of 'inferior-octave-prompt'.

Answer (score 5):

From http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?41099#comment4:

1. Add `PS1(">> ")` to `~/.octaverc`
2. Add `(setq inferior-octave-prompt ">> ")` to `~/.emacs.d/init.el` (or wherever your Emacs startup is)

This got me going on Ubuntu 14.04, with Emacs 24.3 and Octave 3.8.1.  For future readers: according to the bug report, this should be fixed in Emacs 24.4, so if you encounter a similar problem in that or a later Emacs version, it might be something else.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem and can add a little more information which might be useful. I have been using octave daily for months using emacs 23.4 on several machines that had Ubuntu 13.04 installed. Everything worked with the octave mode. A few days ago I updated one of the machines to 14.04 Ubuntu. M-x run-octave stopped working at that point. It freezes partway through the welcome menu. Octave  works fine in an xterm. I also tried emacs 24. And I tried upgrading octave. My current version of octave is 3.8.1.

The command I have used successfully in the past to launch the inferior octave was C-c C-i l.

Comment: I have the same issue. But I don't see an answer in this anywhere.

Comment: FYI: Rory York's solution did work for me. I've been using it successfully since mid August '14.