# Emacs freezes when running an Octave code block within org-mode

Tags: emacs, octave, org-mode, org-babel

My spec: emacs 24.3.1, octave 3.8.1

Code example:

```
#+name: factor
#+begin_src octave :session *octave* :exports code :results silent
factor=4;
#+end_src
```

My emacs crashes also when `M-x run-octave`

Comment: On what operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Given your versions of Emacs and Octave, your problem may be due a change in Octave 3.8 prompt that hasn't been updated in Emacs 24.3 `octave-mode` (it should be fixed in 24.4). Try adding `PS1(">> ")` to your `~/.octaverc` and see if that resolves the problem.

Attribution:

1. https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?41099
2. [Inferior octave freezes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709653/inferior-octave-freezes)